# What 'no such child' means in java swing when trying to makeCompactGrid with class SpringUtilities

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

So I tried to make a simple java swing program, i didn't finish the program but I wanted to see how it looks before doing the functionality part, this is my code:

```
import layouts.SpringUtilities;

import javax.swing.*;
import layouts.SpringUtilities;


public class FactorialCalculatorFrame extends JFrame {

    public FactorialCalculatorFrame(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());


        JTextField brojText = new JTextField();
        brojText.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Broj:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(brojText);


        JButton start = new JButton("Start");

        panel.add(new JLabel("Pokreni izracun:",SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(start);


        JProgressBar napredakProgressBar = new JProgressBar();

        add(new JLabel("Napredak:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        add(napredakProgressBar);

        JLabel rezultat = new JLabel("Rezultat:");
        JLabel ispisiRez = new JLabel("");

        add(new JLabel("Rezultat:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        add(ispisiRez);


        start.addActionListener((e)->{
            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(brojText.getText());

                //reset GUI components
                napredakProgressBar.setValue(0);
                start.setEnabled(false);
                ispisiRez.setText("");

                //schedule for execution on one of working threads
                new primeNumberJavaSwingApp().execute();

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel,4, 2, 0, 0, 5, 5);

        add(panel);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FactorialCalculatorFrame frame = new FactorialCalculatorFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class primeNumberJavaSwingApp extends SwingWorker<Long, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Long l = (long)3.2;
return l;}}}
```

```
the Exception that occurs is this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 4
at layouts.SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(SpringUtilities.java:190)
at FactorialCalculatorFrame.<init>(FactorialCalculatorFrame.java:55)
```

Why does this occurs, what did I do wrong?

I also use SpringUtilities class that I copied from Oracle.
Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) for working examples. I've never used the SpringLayout before since it is overly complicatied. So as my wild guess, I see that you define 4 rows and 2 columns but I only see you add 4 components to the panel.  and I would suggest you can use the GridBagLayout just as easily. The tutorial also has example on using the GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded source code for class `SpringUtilities` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java).

Your problem is that you are not adding all the components to the `panel`. You are calling `add()` when you should be calling `panel.add()`. Hence you are only adding 4 components to `panel` rather than 8. Hence the error message.

I also added a call to method `pack()`, of class `JFrame`, in order to make the `JFrame` big enough to display all the components it contains.

Here is your code with my fixes:

```java
import layout.SpringUtilities; // in your code this import is added twice

import javax.swing.*;

public class FactorialCalculatorFrame extends JFrame {
    public FactorialCalculatorFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // I added this line
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());

        JTextField brojText = new JTextField();
        brojText.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Broj:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(brojText);

        JButton start = new JButton("Start");

        panel.add(new JLabel("Pokreni izracun:",SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(start);

        JProgressBar napredakProgressBar = new JProgressBar();

        panel.add(new JLabel("Napredak:", SwingConstants.RIGHT)); // change here
        panel.add(napredakProgressBar); // change here

        JLabel rezultat = new JLabel("Rezultat:");
        JLabel ispisiRez = new JLabel("");

        panel.add(new JLabel("Rezultat:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(ispisiRez);

        start.addActionListener((e)->{
            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(brojText.getText());

                //reset GUI components
                napredakProgressBar.setValue(0);
                start.setEnabled(false);
                ispisiRez.setText("");

                //schedule for execution on one of working threads
                new primeNumberJavaSwingApp().execute();

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 4, 2, 0, 0, 5, 5);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FactorialCalculatorFrame frame = new FactorialCalculatorFrame();
        frame.pack(); // I added this line
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // I added this line
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class primeNumberJavaSwingApp extends SwingWorker<Long, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Long l = (long) 3.2;
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the `JFrame` when running the above code.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes it was a typo, thank you a lot and yes pack() method is very useful